# How to create a class that uses odd-child pseudo selector with tailwindcss

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm having some difficulty using the [odd-child](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pseudo-class-variants/#odd-child) psuedo selector in a class.  odd:bg-blue-200 works fine when using it inline. But i'd like to extract this style so all of my table rows have this style when given class .tr. I've been reviewing the docs but the solution is eluding me. I hope someone here can help.

so far, i've tried:

```css
.tr:odd {
  @apply bg-blue-200;
}
```

and

```css
@variants odd {
  .tr {
    @apply bg-blue-200;
  }

}
```

in tailwind.config.js, i've added the backgroundColor variant:

```js
variants: {
'backgroundColor': ['responsive', 'odd', 'hover']
},
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a vanilla css rule can do the trick in combination with @apply of tailwind.
*(A config change for this is not required.)*

```
.tr:nth-child(odd) {
    @apply bg-blue-200;
}
```

Comment: That's how i got it to work. i'm still lost on how to do it using tailwinds syntax.

Comment: This is the tailwind recommended syntax:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives/#apply
The same is for 'hover', 'focus' and all the pseudo-classes.

Answer (score 1):

A more recent way to achieve a similar thing without writing a custom CSS rule is to use the new(ish) arbitrary selectors as a single class to apply to the parent element (e.g. `tbody`):

```
[&>tr:nth-child(odd)]:bg-gray-100
```

```
& - self referential
>tr - direct children that are `tr`s
nth-child(odd) - only odd children
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an `@import "./custom-utilities.css";` as the last line in my `tailwind.css`.

I want to use the even/odd CSS only below a class named `.markdown`, so my relevant section from the `custom-utilities.css` looks like this:

```
.markdown {
    & tbody tr {
        @apply ;
    }
    & tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
        @apply bg-gray-100;
    }
}
```

The strange thing is: the CSS for `tr:nth-child(odd)` only gets applied if the empty `@apply` for `tr` is present. Is this a bug in Tailwind CSS? I'm using `1.9.3` at the moment, but I'm sure that it used to work without the first block (with the empty `@apply`) for a previous version.

AFAIK, it's not necessary to include `odd` in the `variants` section in `tailwind.config.js` because it's included by default.