# use nth-child(odd) css selector with Tailwind on the parent element

Tags: css, css-selectors, tailwind-css

I'm trying to achieve the following:

```html
<table>
  <tr class="odd:bg-white even:bg-slate-100">
    <td>name</td>
    <td>title1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd:bg-white even:bg-slate-100">
    <td>name</td>
    <td>title1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd:bg-white even:bg-slate-100">
    <td>name</td>
    <td>title1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But without entering the css on each `tr` child tag, but once on the `table` tag.

Something like this: (which I couldn't make it work, btw)

```html
<table class="--odd:bg-white even:bg-slate-100 [&:nth-child(odd)]:bg-gray-400">
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>title1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>title1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>title1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Right now I'm doing something like this to achieve it, but I'd like to do it all with tailwind classes, if possible

```css
<style lang="postcss">
    div.plan-details :nth-child(odd) {
        @apply text-zinc-500;
    }
    div.plan-details :nth-child(even) {
        @apply text-zinc-900;
    }
</style>
```

Also tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74109547/47633) but it didn't work.

I have this [tailwind play example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/rbMgKtL79d) with both examples

Comment: Is this solution of creating a class not giving you a good solution? Are you looking for a way to do it without custom utilities? Example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/NRb0AhM7qE

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's similar to what I'm doing, I'm just trying to avoid setting any css, and try to solve it with inline classes, if it's possible

Comment: I couldn't figure it out, but I found out about a plugin the developer created: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/8299 If you want to add it to tailwind, check this link: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-variants It might get you closer to the solution

Comment: Check out what I have successfully done. Maybe we can figure it out together: https://play.tailwindcss.com/dEqsiZ241R So it works with the list and div elements but not the table elements..

Comment: You are pretty close @ChenBr, later on I'll see why it doesn't work with tables and trs

Comment: I found a solution, and I am posting it now :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to use [Arbitrary variants](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/8299). To put it simply:

> `&` is self-referential which means `children:pl-4` will result in `.children\:pl-4 > * { .. }`

To apply this logic to `odd` and `even` children, we'll use the `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` selectors giving them different background colors:

```
[&>*:nth-child(odd)]:bg-blue-500
[&>*:nth-child(even)]:bg-red-500
```

##### In practice:

```
<div class=" [&>*:nth-child(odd)]:bg-red-500 [&>*:nth-child(even)]:bg-blue-500">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

[image: div]

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/mvcQlEny94)

---

While this method works fine on `div` and `li` elements, it doesn't seem to work on table elements...

The user [Wongjn](https://github.com/wongjn) pointed out to me that the browser injects a `<tbody>` element. This is why the above method is applied to all the elements when selecting odd-numbered elements. Our selector chose only one element, the `<tbody>` element!

> Yes, the browser will often inject a `<tbody>` element between the `<table>` and  elements if it does not exist, so the direct descendent selectors evaluate against the `<tbody>`, not the `<tr>` elements

[image: tbody]

---

To work around the `<tbody>` injection, we can change the selector to choose the child of the `<tbody>`:

```
[&>tbody>*:nth-child(odd)]
```

##### In practice:

```
<table class=" [&>tbody>*:nth-child(odd)]:bg-red-500 [&>tbody>*:nth-child(even)]:bg-blue-500">
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>title1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>title1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>title1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

[Tailwind-Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/l5rRu1Fthy)

As [opensas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47633/opensas) suggested, it is possible to insert the `<tbody>` manually:

> That's great, I guess we could also explicitly add the tbody ourselves, to avoid that browser magic, like this: [Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/GitWWTJNFM)

```html
<table>
  <tbody class="[&>*:nth-child(odd)]:bg-red-500 [&>*:nth-child(even)]:bg-blue-500">
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>title1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>title1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>title1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's great, I guess we could also explicitly add the tbody ourselves, to avoid that browser magic, like this: https://play.tailwindcss.com/GitWWTJNFM
still surprises me that something so common is not easier to achieve with tailwind

Comment: @opensas Good point, I added it to the answer as well. I definitely agree, the way those selectors are implemented right now is quite annoying..

Answer (score 0):

in tailwind there are several props explore a little one day.. you can use the Even prop of tailwind in the parent div of its children, like this:

```
<div className={`even:mt-8`}>
      <div>
        {/* Content*/}
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.2 tailwind supports combining groups with arbitrary value.

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="group-[:nth-of-type(3)_&]:block">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

You can put the `group` className to the any parent element (in your case tr) and change styles of the any child using `group-[*]:` variant.